# Translate word doc - Google Api Translate

Tags: java, google-api, google-translate

I've already achieve to translate, with Google API translate, some plain text from a textarea or from a .txt file but nothing from a word doc (by word doc i mean .doc/.docx files). I only have an unreadable content when i get my doc content in java (i have an ajax call who get the file content which it filled by the user into an input file).

Do i have to transform my word doc content to plain text before calling the API or maybe Google have a simply way to translate a word doc through their API ?

I hope i'm clear enough..

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can send `plain text` and `HTML` file to the Translation API as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/). You can also take a look in the [Query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#query-parameters) of API's `translate` method that states the `format` parameter should be `plain text` or `HTML`. In your case, I think you should have to extract the text from the document as plain text before you send it to the Translation API.

Comment: I think I have to transform my docs into plain text before translate too. Thanks